# argument value in function is not changing it's value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my function. It is increasing and decreasing the Qt-Quantity value, where ${qt}. However, the value qt from AddToCart function is not changing(not updating). How can I fix this?

```js
function ShowTheMenu(theCategoryId) {
    // bt+
    increaseBtn = (i) => {
        let item = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
        let qtSpan = item.getElementsByClassName('qt');
        let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
        if (qt === undefined || !qt) qt = 1;
        if (qt < 10) qt++;
        qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt;
    };

    // bt-
    decreaseBtn = (i) => {
        let item = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
        let qtSpan = item.getElementsByClassName('qt');
        let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
        if (qt === undefined || !qt) qt = 1;
        if (qt > 1) qt--;
        qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt;
    };


    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].KategorijaBroj == theCategoryId) {
            let itemId = data[i].Id;
            let img = "/menuitemsimages/" + data[i].Image;
            let title = data[i].Title;
            let price = '$' + data[i].Price;
            let desc = data[i].Description;

            var qt = 1;
            let newItem = `<div id="item_${i}" class="itembox">
                                      <img src="${img}" class="itemimage"/>
                                      <div class="itemcontent"> 
                                        <h3 class="itemtitle">${title}</h3>
                                        <p class="description">${desc}</p>
                                        <p class="itemprice">${price}</p>
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <span>Quantity</span>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="divcontrolbtns">
                                          <button class="controlbtns" onClick="increaseBtn(${i})">+</button>
                                            <span class="qt">${qt}</span>
                                          <button class="controlbtns" onClick="decreaseBtn(${i})">-</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn-add-to-cart" onClick='AddToCart(${qt}, ${itemId})'>Add to cart</button>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>`;

            // Get the menulist itens
            let parentEl = document.getElementById('itemlist');
            // Add item
            parentEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem);
        }
    }
}
```

-Here is HTML button with the AddToCart function,where 1 is quantity and 27 is the itemId;

```
<button class="btn-add-to-cart" onclick="AddToCart(1, 27)">Add to cart</button>
```

AddToCart Function

```
function AddToCart(qt, itemId) {
    var url = "https://localhost:44335/Cart/Order";
    var data = {
        Quantity: qt,
        ItemId: itemId
    }
    axios.post(url, data)
        .then(function (response) {

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, why don't you update the onclick attribute of your button?

Comment: How can I target that attribute? Right now, the span with class='qt' is changing the value

Comment: You didn't post to your AddToCart function here so I can only guess, but there are several ways to access your button. The easiest would be to add a unique ID to it and then do document.getElementById('your_cart_btn_ID').setAttribute('onclick','AddToCart('+newQuantity+', 27)');

Comment: AddToCart function is sending the data to .Net endpoint. I just updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :**
Following your clarifications in the comments I understand you only need to update the onclick attribute of the button in the `increaseBtn` and `decreaseBtn` functions.

```
increaseBtn = (i) => {
    let item = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
    let qtSpan = item.getElementsByClassName('qt');
    let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
    if (qt === undefined || !qt) qt = 1;
    if (qt < 10) qt++;
    qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt;
    
    // update AddToCart onclick Btn
    document.getElementById('add_to_cart_btn_'+i).setAttribute('onclick','AddToCart('+qt+', '+i+')');
};

// bt-
decreaseBtn = (i) => {
    let item = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
    let qtSpan = item.getElementsByClassName('qt');
    let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
    if (qt === undefined || !qt) qt = 1;
    if (qt > 1) qt--;
    qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt;
    
    // update AddToCart onclick Btn
    document.getElementById('add_to_cart_btn_'+i).setAttribute('onclick','AddToCart('+qt+', '+i+')');
};
```

You'll just need to add a unique ID to your button to access it.

```
<button id="add_to_cart_btn_${itemId}" class="btn-add-to-cart" onClick='AddToCart(${qt}, ${itemId})'>Add to cart</button>
```

**Final note :**
your increaseBtn and decreaseBtn are 99% the same, you should replace it by a unique `changeQT(i, step)` instead (step being 1 or -1 here)

Comment: When AddToCart function receives qt=1(its' default) then data Quantity is set to 1. There is no point after to increase the value of the qt. I will include image to be more clear

Comment: @peter The code I gave you will work as follow : 1st click qt=1, 2nd click qt=2, 3rd click qt=3, ... Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There are increaseBtn and decreaseBtn functions which are setting       qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt; I want beside qtSpan[0] the AddToCart(-->QT<--, itemId) to be updated as well. If you can notice on the image, the value is increased to 3, however AddToCart function has 1 qt

Comment: @peter OK, now I think I understand what you want to do. The onclick attribute of the button should be updated in the increaseBtn and decreaseBtn functions, you'll just need to add a unique ID to your button. Let me just edit my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I got "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"...the button has its own id add_to_cart_btn_01 but still when I try to increase or decrease the value I'm getting the error above.

Comment: @peter Is the value of the variable "i" set to 1 or "01" ? If your button ID is set to "add_to_cart_btn_01" you will need to convert your one-digit numbers to 2 characters string. It would probably be easier to set your ID to "add_to_cart_btn_1" instead.

Comment: the for loop i it starts from 0. Here is one buttonId - add_to_cart_btn_25

Comment: Alright, I finally fixed it. AddToCart function is getting i instead of qt and in the function    var theQT = document.getElementById("item_" + i);
    let qtSpan = theQT.getElementsByClassName('qt');
    let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
    console.log(qt);

Comment: @peter Then your button ID should be set to "add_to_cart_btn_1" and not "add_to_cart_btn_01".